# sql queries foreign key error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

can anyone help me with that error?

```
CONSTRAINT a_id FOREIGN KEY(A_id) REFERENCES PAINTING
                                                   *
```

number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

My queries are below:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTIST
(
     A_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
     Name VARCHAR2(50) ,
     DOB NUMBER(10) ,
     DOD NUMBER(10) ,
     Nationality VARCHAR2(50) ,
      CONSTRAINT a_id FOREIGN KEY(A_id) REFERENCES PAINTING
);


CREATE TABLE PAINTING
(
     P_id NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
     Title NUMBER(10) ,
     Value NUMBER(10) ,
     Aquisition_date DATE NOT NULL,
     Insurance_value NUMBER(10),
 CONSTRAINT prim_key PRIMARY KEY(P_id, Aquisition_date),
 CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (P_id) REFERENCES  IN_GALLERY,
  CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (P_id) REFERENCES  ON_LOAN,
  CONSTRAINT fk3 FOREIGN KEY (P_id) REFERENCES  OWNER_HISTORY
);
```

Comment: Your data model makes no sense, even if you fixed the syntax.

Comment: MySQL does not support NUMBER or VARCHAR2 datatypes. please tag the correct database you are using. i geuss you are using SQL-server.

Comment: SQL*Plus from a terminal !

Comment: @PinelopiConstantinou, I guess you are using Oracle? See the answer below based on my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key has to reference a primary key not just partial columns.

Table PAINTING has a composite primary key on A_id and Aquisition_date. Try this. It should work.

```
CREATE TABLE PAINTING
(
     P_id NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
     Title NUMBER(10) ,
     Value NUMBER(10) ,
     Aquisition_date DATE NOT NULL,
     Insurance_value NUMBER(10),
 CONSTRAINT prim_key PRIMARY KEY(P_id, Aquisition_date)
);





CREATE TABLE ARTIST
(
     A_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
     Name VARCHAR2(50) ,
     DOB NUMBER(10) ,
     DOD NUMBER(10) ,
     Nationality VARCHAR2(50) ,
     p_id  NUMBER,
     Aquisition_date DATE,
     CONSTRAINT fk_painting FOREIGN KEY(P_id, Aquisition_date) REFERENCES PAINTING
);
```

I removed the constraints for the other tables you had. Add them back if you need to.

Comment: i had a question. When i create a foreign key, i also have to create an attribute in the table that is references??

Comment: Hi again, what if i have an error such as : " ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here"??